# Universal linking iOS - where is the .xcodeproj file?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-universal-links

I've been trying for days to get Universal Linking working on iOS for React Native.

The docs [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#enabling-deep-links) say "On iOS, you'll need to link RCTLinking to your project". I'm then told to go to `node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS` and drag a `.xcodeproj` file into my project.

None of the libraries in the `Libraries` folder whatsoever have any `.xodeproj` files in them.

Is there meant to be? Is my `react-native` instance missing something? Googling this issue pulls up nothing at all - does everyone else have `.xcodeproj` files in their `Libraries` folder??

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Starting with version 0.60 React Native provides auto-linking.

To have the library available in RN versions newer than 0.60 you have to:

**1) Add reference to `LinkingIOS` folder into header search paths**
in

`Xcode -> project target -> projectName ->Build Settings -> header search paths:`

[image]

`$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS`

**2) Import it in `AppDelegate.m`**

`#import "RCTLinkingManager.h"`

About the other steps that you need to do:

- **upload an apple app site association file to your web server**,
- **preparing the app for universal linking in developer.apple.com** and
- **setting up universal links in Xcode and RN code**

you can check this link:

https://www.ekreative.com/blog/universal-linking-in-react-native-for-ios/

Just ignore the manual linking paragraph on that page.

Comment: !!! thank you SO much, I can't believe how difficult it was to find this information anywhere. You're the best.